# Usage of "hier" to convey "yesterday" as in "I need this report yesterday"

Tags: traduction, anglais, usage, expressions-idiomatiques

Yesterday has an idiomatic usage which is basically a synonym for "as soon as possible".

> I need those reports, and I need them yesterday. ≈ I need them ASAP.
>
> We want to see them in a concert. Bring them for a live yesterday!

Can "hier" be used with a similar meaning?

E.g. does

> On veut les voir en concert. Amenez-les pour un concert hier!

sound idiomatic?

Comment: The first example about reports and "yesterday" as ASAP works perfectly, but For a ?live [show?], I'm confused by this phrasing in English.  Parsing "We wanted to see them live yesterday" doesn't convey hyperbole/sarcasm, like "Hier on voulait voir en direct/en concert (mais on a loupé)."  Problème et bonne question.

I once heard a comedian say [Je vous rappelle] dès que posthume.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No, *amenez-les pour un concert hier* is not idiomatic and would be puzzling.

That doesn't mean *hier* is never used with such a meaning. For example, to the question

> *Quand voulez-vous que les rapports soient rendus ?*  (When would you like the reports to be delivered?)

the answer might be:

> *Il me les faudrait pour hier !* (I'd need them by yesterday!)